# Plotting average observation counts by weekday and hour across multiple dates using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with each observation representation an object in the real world I have counted using OpenCV. After some mutations and using tidyverse and lubridate my dataframe looks like this:

```
> head(odcCountsRoadUsers)
       frameId objectClass dayOfWeek ymdhms              hourOfDay
  1    1133    car         1         2021-12-05 13:45:25 13
  2    1159    car         1         2021-12-05 13:45:26 13
  3    1243    car         1         2021-12-05 13:45:31 13
  4    1280    person      1         2021-12-05 13:45:33 13
  5    1305    bus         1         2021-12-05 13:45:34 13
  6    1812    person      1         2021-12-05 13:46:03 13
```

I have data for multiple days, also containing multiple counts for the same `dayOfWeek`. What I want to do is create a histogram for each day of the week (7 in total) with the number of observations for each hour of the day. The result should look similar to this (one histogram per day of the week):

[image]

My problems are:

1. How do I use ggplot2 so that it uses the POSIXct `ymdhms` as x-axis and for the y-axis does an aggregation of the number of observations by `hourOfDay` (or directly using `ymdhms` if that's possible) and filters by `dayOfWeek`?
2. Since I have multiple days with records I only want the average for a `dayOfWeek` and not simple add the count of all observations for different dates together. How can I do this efficiently? Does it make sense to create a separate dataframe for that before plotting or can this be done easily using `ggplot2`?

Bonus question regarding a chance to separate/group by `objectClass`, but those two are the most pressing questions I cannot seem to figure out on my own.

The [source data is available on GitHub](https://github.com/yauh/opendatacam-statistics) if that helps.

Comment: You said you have mutated the original data with some operations and you show the data after. Can you provide a little example of your actual data with samples for at least 2 `dayOfWeek` with different dates (for question 2) and some hours each one after you mutated the dataframe? So we can jump right to the question.

Comment: Thanks @RobertoT. Since the existing answer already covers what't needed I won't give more details (those could be found in the GitHub repo linked above if you're still curious).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can summarize e.g. over all Mondays in a given hour using the `dplyr` package. After that summation, the x axis is just a number from 0 to 23 which is not of the type POSIXct representing a specific, unambiguous time point any more.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

data <-
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yauh/opendatacam-statistics/main/input/counterData-2022-01-23-61ed51ecae46bd0088feb8f5.csv" %>%
  read_csv(col_names = FALSE) %>%
  transmute(
    frameId = X1,
    objectClass = X4,
    time = X2
  )
#> 
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> cols(
#>   X1 = col_double(),
#>   X2 = col_datetime(format = ""),
#>   X3 = col_character(),
#>   X4 = col_character(),
#>   X5 = col_double(),
#>   X6 = col_double(),
#>   X7 = col_character(),
#>   X8 = col_double()
#> )
data
#> # A tibble: 77,966 × 3
#>    frameId objectClass time               
#>      <dbl> <chr>       <dttm>             
#>  1    6369 person      2022-01-23 13:02:37
#>  2    6457 car         2022-01-23 13:02:42
#>  3    6494 car         2022-01-23 13:02:45
#>  4    6583 car         2022-01-23 13:02:51
#>  5    6587 car         2022-01-23 13:02:51
#>  6    6767 car         2022-01-23 13:03:03
#>  7    6926 car         2022-01-23 13:03:14
#>  8    7201 car         2022-01-23 13:03:32
#>  9    7237 car         2022-01-23 13:03:35
#> 10    7409 car         2022-01-23 13:03:46
#> # … with 77,956 more rows

aggregated_data <-
  data %>%
  mutate(
    weekday = wday(time, label = TRUE),
    hour = hour(time),
    date = date(time)
  ) %>%
  count(weekday, date, hour) %>%
  # average e.g over all mondays
  group_by(weekday, hour) %>%
  summarise(n = mean(n))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'weekday'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
aggregated_data
#> # A tibble: 168 × 3
#> # Groups:   weekday [7]
#>    weekday  hour     n
#>    <ord>   <int> <dbl>
#>  1 Sun         0    29
#>  2 Sun         1    17
#>  3 Sun         2    17
#>  4 Sun         3    13
#>  5 Sun         4    44
#>  6 Sun         5    29
#>  7 Sun         6    47
#>  8 Sun         7   103
#>  9 Sun         8   245
#> 10 Sun         9   362
#> # … with 158 more rows

aggregated_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(hour, n)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~weekday)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

If you want to compare differences at each weekday, it is also a good idea to plot them together:

```
aggregated_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(hour, n, color = weekday)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Adding the object class as an argument of `group_by` allows us for additional stratification:

```
aggregated_data2 <-
  data %>%
  mutate(
    weekday = wday(time, label = TRUE),
    hour = hour(time),
    date = date(time)
  ) %>%
  count(objectClass, weekday, date, hour) %>%
  # average e.g over all mondays for each object class
  group_by(objectClass, weekday, hour) %>%
  summarise(n = mean(n))

aggregated_data2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(hour, n, color = objectClass)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~weekday, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed, thanks so much! This also means that if for one hour no observations exist it does not get plotted? So if I only had observations between 04:00 and 06:00 then the plot would not span 24 hours?

Comment: Yes. No observations will not be plotted. Drawing to y=0 can be enforced using the function `complete` from the tidyr package.